# How do I assign a due date to a card in Trello?

Tags: trello

I want to set a due date on a card in Trello. How do I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trello now has a more sophisticated due date system.

You can add a due date via the sidebar where you get a date picker and time select input. If you have set a due date, you can remove it by clicking the date on the back of the card, and selecting remove from the bottom left hand corner.

The yellow date badge on the front of the card means the card is due within eight hours. If it's red, it means it's late.

Answer (score 14):

Just type `Due 1/1/2020` in your comment and Trello will magically pick it up.

[image: setting a due date]

**EDIT**

Trello now has a new due date system. See Bobby's answer.

Comment: This only accepts the mm/dd/yyyy format is there any way to change this?

Comment: When I did this, I typed in `Due 9/28/2011`. The card now has a date indicator for the 27th. What?

Comment: how do we add time to this?